# Why mathjax don't work in switch case with include html of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mathjax

I use mathjax and include html and when i use this the mathjax doesn't work, but without the switch case it works fine ,why?
JS

```
function change() {
  var x=Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

  switch(x) {
    case 0:
      $(function(){
        $("#erwtisi").load("test.html");
      });
      break;
    case 1:
      $(function(){
        $("#erwtisi").load("test.html");
      });
      break;
   .............etc
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading content after MathJax has already parsed and typeset the data on the page.  Queue another MathJax render as detailed in the docs: [Modifying Math on the Page](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.0/typeset.html#modifying-math-on-the-page).

> If you are writing a dynamic web page where content containing
>   mathematics may appear after MathJax has already typeset the rest of
>   the page, then you will need to tell MathJax to look for mathematics
>   in the page again when that new content is produced. To do that, you
>   need to use the `MathJax.Hub.Typeset()` method. This will cause the
>   preprocessors (if any were loaded) to run over the page again, and
>   then MathJax will look for unprocessed mathematics on the page and
>   typeset it, leaving unchanged any math that has already been typeset.

The suggested use it to queue it using:

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
```